# JasperReports Server compile error for subreports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have designed a report in *iReport* and trying to run it in *JasperReports Server 4.7.0* but getting below errors while executing the report:

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience. 
Error Message
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 
1. Syntax error on token ":", , expected value = {repo:"C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport1.jasper"}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$ ^ 
2. Syntax error on token ":", ; expected value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ ^ 
3. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ <--------------------------------> 
4. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete Expression value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ <----> 
5. Syntax error on token ":", ; expected value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ ^ 
6. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ <--------------------------------> 
7. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete Expression value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ <----> 
8. Syntax error on token ":", , expected value = {repo:"C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport1.jasper"}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$ ^ 
9. Syntax error on token ":", ; expected value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ ^ 
10. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ <--------------------------------> 
11. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete Expression value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ <----> 
12. Syntax error on token ":", ; expected value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ ^ 
13. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ <--------------------------------> 
14. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete Expression value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ <----> 
15. Syntax error on token ":", , expected value = {repo:"C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport1.jasper"}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$ ^ 
16. Syntax error on token ":", ; expected value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ ^ 
17. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ <--------------------------------> 
18. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete Expression value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport2.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$ <----> 
19. Syntax error on token ":", ; expected value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ ^ 
20. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ <--------------------------------> 
21. Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete Expression value = repo:C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\report\\report8_subreport3.jasper; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ <----> 
21 errors
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file of master report. You can read [Uploading Report Units with Subreports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uploading-report-units-subreports) post

Comment: Check your path of subreport.. It may be wrong... post your jrxml file for more clarification.